# Plotting graph from csv flie

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python. I've to plot graphs from a csv file that I've created.
a) Monthly sales vs Product Price
b) Geographic Region vs No of customer

The code that I've implemented was

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import csv

data = pd.read_csv('dataset_books.csv')
data.hist(bins=90)
plot.xlim([0,115054])
plot.title("Data")
x = plot.xlabel("Monthly Sales")
y = plot.ylabel("Product Price")
plot.show()
```

the output that I'm getting is not what I expected and is not approved.
[image]

I need a Horizontal Histogram with line plot.

```
Book ID Product Name    Product Price   Monthly Sales   Shipping Type   Geographic Region   No Of Customer Who Bought the Product   Customer Type
1   The Path to Power   486 2566.08 Free    Gatton  4   Old
2   Touching Darkness (Midnighters, #2) 479 1264.56 Paid    Hooker Creek    2   New
3   Star Wars: Lost Stars   456 1203.84 Paid    Gladstone   2   New
4   Winter in Madrid    454 599.28  Paid    Warruwi 1   New
5   Hairy Maclary from Donaldson's Dairy    442 2333.76 Free    Mount Gambier   4   Old
6   Stand on Zanzibar   413 3816.12 Free    Cessnock    7   Old
7   Marlfox 411 3797.64 Free    Edinburgh   7   Old
8   The Matlock Paper   373 3446.52 Free    Gladstone   7   Old
9   Tears of a Tiger    361 1906.08 Free    Melbourne   4   Old
10  Star Wars: Vision of the Future 355 937.2   Paid    Wagga Wagga 2   New
11  Nefes Nefese    344 454.08  Paid    Gatton  1   New
```

this is my CSV file.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not specify which line of the dataframe you want to plot. Try data[i].hist insted of data.hist

Comment: KeyError: 2I'm getting this error.

Comment: you can specify which columns to plot with the `x` and `y` arguments [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot)

Comment: Yes.
Monthly sales vs Product price and Geographic Region vs No of customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to check your columns name:

```
df.columns
>> Index(['Book ID', 'Product Name', 'Product Price', 'Monthly Sales',
       'Shipping Type', 'Geographic Region',
       'No Of Customer Who Bought the Product', 'Customer Type'],
     dtype='object')
```

Next to plot horizontal plot you need 'barh'.

```
df['Product Price'].plot(kind='barh')
```

[image]

Another option to chose column is 'iloc'

```
df.iloc[:, 2].plot(kind='barh')
```

It will generate the same output

Comment: Thank you that helped.
i have to use plot.show() in order to display the graph.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter

Comment: Also, how do you plot a scatter graph?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
just change kind='scatter'